# How to configure IB gateway on headless server

Tags: java, interactive-brokers

I run IB gateway on headless server, but I want to change default config.
There is a question. It will read config file from a random directory when IB gateway starting. I don't know this dir's name. when I restart it, it will create new dir. So, someone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

IB gateway's 'random' configuration directory name actually isn't random, it corresponds to the user name you use to login. You can login on your desktop and then login on the headless server with same user, and compare the 'random' directory generated. They should have same name.

To configure IB gateway on headless server, I use Mac desktop to set the configurations, and then copy the files under the directory corresponds to the login user name to Linux headless server. It works as expected.